# How do I parse a string to output it's content between word X and word Y?

Tags: batch-file

Let's say I have a query like this coming up as an output of a findstr command in a batch script:

```
select a, b, c FROM table1, table2, table3 WHERE something happens
```

or like this

```
select a, b, c from table1
```

I want to pick the table names and to put them somewhere.
Now, the problem is about that first step of 'cutting' out whatever is in between the FROM and either the WHERE condition
    or the end of the query. I checked the batch string management tools and nothing seems to be helpful since
    most of them are based on knowing the exact position of the data I want to exctract. For simplicity's sake
    assume that there are no exeeding spaces to trim away and that there are no more than one FROM and WHERE
    word per query. Any leads?

Comment: You said you checked the "batch string management tools", but why don't you share your efforts?

Comment: Try a look at `set /?` especially `%PATH:str1=str2%` and `if str starts with a star ...`

Comment: Sure, now that you mention it, saying "string manipulating tools" would have been more correct. As far as my efforts went, I did not even manage to hypotize a possible working way to spilt out that string by using batch. Right now my obstacle is that I don't see any way of knowing the exact character slot the FROM starts allowing me to do the rest of the job with the available manipulation operations. A couple minutes ago I realized I could make a script that deletes every character from the left until the word FROM is found at the begin of the string but I'm not yet sure if this is possible.

Comment: What if the query does not have WHERE but does have GROUP BY or ORDER BY?

Comment: For that matter I may find a solution, the matter is that I didn't find any "grabbing point" to approach the problem of manipulating strings without a positional syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string substitution with a wildcard to isolate pre-/suffix

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\12\06\SO_53652818.cmd
@Echo off
set "string=select a, b, c FROM table1, table2, table3 WHERE something happens"

set "suffix=%string:*where=%"
call set "string=%%string: where%suffix%=%%"
set "tables=%string:* from =%%"
set tables

set "string=select a, b, c from table1"

set "suffix=%string:*where=%"
call set "string=%%string: where%suffix%=%%"
set "tables=%string:* from =%%"
set tables
```

Or change the words `where`,`from` to a single char delimiter

```
@Echo off
set "string=select a, b, c FROM table1, table2, table3 WHERE something happens"

set "string=%string: where =|%"
set "string=%string: from =|%"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%A in ("%string%") Do set "tables=%%A"
set tables
```

Just another alternative using PowerShell as a tool with
a regular expression featering lookarounds (zero length assertions) which avoids the pitfalls mentioned by [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham)

```
@Echo off
set "string=select a, b, c FROM table1, table2, table3 WHERE Country='Mexico'"
For /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`
  powershell -NoP -C "if($ENV:String -match '(?<=FROM ).*?(?= (WHERE|GROUP|ORDER))'){$Matches[0]}"
`) do set "tables=%%A"
set tables
```

Comment: Now that's a good idea, the first metod could even work with no exceptions in my case. Your answers are always on point, thanks boss.

Comment: First method will fail if the WHERE clause includes `=`, which is very common in typical SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler:

```
@echo off

set "string=select a, b, c FROM table1, table2, table3 WHERE something happens"

set "string=%string: WHERE =" & rem "%"
set "string=%string: FROM =" & set "tables=%"

set tables
```

I could write an ample explanation of the method used, but it is much simpler if you just remove the `@echo off` line, run the program and carefuly review the executed code...

If you have any further question, post a comment.

Comment: Hi, your code works perfectly for me (I added the ecceptions I didn't mention in the question like the ORDER BY, syntax errors ecc.) but out of curiosity I'd steel apreciate clearly understanding how it works, informations about the mechanics you used are pretty confused on official documentations (I think some parts are even missing from it but don't quote me on that) I'd like to better understand that line in particular: `set "string=%string: WHERE =" & rem "%"` I tried the echo off and some other experiments but it's still black magic to me, can you provide me an explanation? I appreciate.

Comment: This is a _very simple_ substring substitution: it just changes `_WHERE_` in the string by `" & rem "` and, _after that_, it executes the remaining line. I suggest you to replicate the same process: open a text file and start with this line: `set "string=select a, b, c FROM table1, table2, table3 WHERE something happens"`. Then, perform the previous change. After that, see the result and realize that such a line will be _executed_... Ta daaa! You'll see the magic! Isn't it? **`;)`**

Comment: If you want to see more examples on this method (and the birth of it, indeed) you may review [this thread](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429), but I warn you that such examples are not as simple as this one...